# Generate Date ranges in JodaTime

Tags: java, jodatime

I need to check if a date(in string) exists in array list.

I have two dates, first i need to generate date ranges between these two dates and store them in an Array. This is what I am doing.

```
DateTimeFormatter dateFromatter= DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");

DateTime startDate= formatter.parseDateTime("01/02/2012");
DateTime endDate= formatter.parseDateTime("01/31/2012");

 List<LocalDate> dates = new ArrayList<LocalDate>();


  int days = Days.daysBetween(startDate, endDate).getDays();
  for (int i=0; i < days; i++) {
```

This is where i am getting problem.

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from DateTime to LocalDate

>   LocalDate listOfDates =
> startDate.withFieldAdded(DurationFieldType.days(), i);
> dates.add(listOfDates);

  }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use org.joda.time.Interval

```
Interval interval = new Interval(startDate, endDate);  
for (LocalDate date : dates)  
{   
  if (interval.contains(date))  
   //
```

Comment: This is incorrect as LocalDate 'date' is only a ReadablePartial not a ReadableInstant.  You _could_ create an interval using startDate and endDate (which are DateTimes) and then test if the date.toDateMidnight() is in the interval, but be careful with the endDate as it is exclusive in an interval.

Answer (score 4):

Doesn't [`toLocalDate()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#toLocalDate%28%29) work?

```
LocalDate listOfDates = 
    startDate.withFieldAdded(DurationFieldType.days(), i).toLocalDate();
```

Anyway, do you really need to generate each date? Unless I really need to, I would just do something similar to this:

```
Interval interval = new Interval(startDate.withTimeAsStartOfDay(), 
                                 endDate.withTimeAsStartOfDay().plusDays(1));
boolean isInInterval = interval.contains(date.withTimeAsStartOfDay());
```

Answer (score 4):

I came here looking for this, but neither solutions were acceptable to me - I ended up with the following:

```
int days = Days.daysBetween(startDate, endDate).getDays();

for(int i = 0; i <= days; i++) {
    dates.add(startDate.plusDays(i));
}
```

Bear in mind that LocalDates are immutable so you're not actually changing it when you call plusDays(...). Also notice that I use <= to include the final day (in your example this would be 31st January).